# Decrease or increase % pivot table calculation in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

This might be a easy question to answer but I'm not finding the logic behind . When I use the % difference of on my pivot table to compare 2022 and 2023 sales , I find the increase logic correct. Based on the example , 2022 year retailer sold 100 but in 2023 he did 650 which is an increase of 550%.... now if the numbers are the other way around , I'm expecting to use -550% but excel gives me -84.62% which makes no sense to me. There is a clear decrease of 500 which I do not think is 84% decrease.. Maybe the % difference of only works for increase ? . Any idea how to fix this so it shows -550% ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: -85% is correct. Going from sales of 650 to 100, means the percent change is (100-650)/650, which is a little over -85%.